# Laravel - Passing Parameters/ undefined variable

Tags: laravel

I'm struggling with passing parameters through in Laravel, I can access it via URL but I don't want that. I'm getting Undefined variable: user in the master.blade error.

Any help is appreciated

AuthController.php

```
 function viewUserDetails($userId)
{
    $user = User::find($userId);
    return view('user/userdetails',['user' => $user]);
}
```

Web.php

```
Route::get('userdetails/{userId}', 'AuthController@viewUserDetails');
```

Master.Blade

```
<li><a href="{{url('userdetails/'.$user->id)}}">Your Details</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Other guys are telling you about `userdetails` view, but your code is totally fine. What you need to do is pass `$user` variable to the `master` view too:

```
return view('master', ['user' => $user]);
```

Comment: Hi, I'm still getting undefined variable user from my master.blade file

Comment: Please show the method which renders `master` view.

Comment: This is embarassing but I don't know what you mean...which file would it be?

Comment: @TF120 I can't see your controllers and routes, so I can't help. The error says the variable in the `master` view. It means some route/controller renders this view and you got the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass like this

```
return view('user/userdetails')->with('user' => $user);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Controller::**

```
function viewUserDetails($userId)
    {
        $user = User::find($userId);
        return view('user.userdetails')-with('user',$user);
    }
```

**Then Used In blade File..**

```
@foreach ($user as $data){

    <h1> {{ $data['_id'] }} </h1>
    <h1> {{ $data['name'] }} </h1>                                 
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have extended `master.blade` in `user/userdetails.blade`. You need use `array` as second parameter to `url` function.

```
<li><a href="{{url('userdetails/', [$user->id])}}">Your Details</a></li>
```

**It is best practice to use named route in laravel.**

Change your route like this :

```
Route::get('userdetails/{userId}', 'AuthController@viewUserDetails')->named('user_details');
```

In your blade you can use `route` function to get the path.

```
<li><a href="{{route('user_details', ['userId' => $user->id])}}">Your Details</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update your code like:

*AuthController.php*

```
function viewUserDetails($userId)
{
   $user = User::find($userId);
   return view('user.userdetails',compact('user'));
}
```

*Web.php*

```
Route::get('userdetails/{userId}', 'AuthController@viewUserDetails');
```

*Master.Blade*

```
<li><a href="{{url('userdetails/',$user->id)}}">Your Details</a></li>
```